reference for Lemma 1.5 of Fermat's dream book
I am looking for another reference to the following Lemma in the elliptic curve chapter 1 of the book "Number Theory 1: Fermat’s Dream" by Kato, Kurokawa, Saito. The proof was left out as obvious, which I agree, but the motivation behind it is far from clear. I vaguely recall Silverman's baby elliptic curve book may have something like this in the appendix, motivating from the projective geometry angle. Is it because the cubic curve degenerates to 3 quadratic curves? Is there a way to be able to see the formula immediately without calculation?


This is a special case of the general fact that elliptic curves can be described either by Weierstrass equations or as the intersection of two quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$. This is in some sense classical but I don't know a good source for it.
